# Is it possible to push as a different user?

Tags: git, github

I'm creating a web-based PHP client for managing site content with Git. I want to associate commits with the various people that are logged in the admin panel. I know I can do this with:

```
git commit --message="foo" --author="John Doe <john@example.com>"
```

However, you can also push to a remote repository (in my case, hosted on GitHub) through the admin panel as well. I can't seem to set the name/email of the *committer* with something like:

```
git push origin master --author="John Doe <john@example.com>"
```

...so in GitHub, the author is John Doe, but the *committer* is me:

[image: git push example]

---

I noticed that the committer is based on the Git config. So I *can* change it and get the correct result:

[image: git push as correct author]

---

My question is, do I need to do this:

```
git config user.name {{ panel user name }}
git config user.email {{ panel user email }}
git push origin master
```

...every time someone pushes to the repo, or there's a better way? I like how you can specify the author in `git commit`. Can this somehow be achieved with `git push` as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The author and committer are actually stored as part of the commit object itself, when it is created. So if you want to customize the author and committer names, you need to do it when running `git commit`. According to [the official documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#_commit_information), you can set both the author and committer information with these four environment variables:

```
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME
GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL
GIT_COMMITTER_NAME
GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL
```

Or alternatively, you can pass custom temporary configuration options to `git` using [the `-c` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt--cltnamegtltvaluegt).

```
git -c user.name="John Doe" -c user.email="john@example.com" commit ...
```

I believe it's more typical to use the environment variables from a script, but I'm not sure why (or, really, if) that is the case.

Note that the `push` command simply sends existing commit objects, including their stored author and committer information, up to the server. You can't change the author or committer while pushing, at least not with standard git as far as I know. I'm not sure how you're managing to pass an `--author` option to `git push`, but it's not listed in [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push).

Comment: No, no, I'm not passing `--author` to `git push`. I simply asked _if_ such a thing (or something similar) exists. If the committer is stored in the Git objects, how can I read it? A `git log` shows only the author.

Comment: Look at the options for `git log` and `git show`, `--full` should do ; you can also use `git cat-file -p <commit>`

Comment: @dodov Sorry, I thought from your question that you were somehow running that `git push` command which you quoted.

Comment: @dodov as LeGEC said, look at the (ridiculously long) set of options for `git log`, in particular the PRETTY LOG FORMATS subsection. `git log` carefully shows you only some *interesting subset* of what's available because "everything" is usually too much. In fact, most of the arguments to `git log` are about cutting down the output to just what you want: `git log --grep` means *cut down based on what's in log messages*, `git log -S` means *cut down based on what's in diffs from parent to child*, etc.